# Как вывести всех студентов из базы данных MYSQL в JAVA

Tags: java, база-данных

Я вывел количество студентов их 6, но как вывести их имя, фамилию, дату рождения, класс. у меня получилось вывести имена и фамилии и тд в самой базе данных. Но я хочу его через netbeans в JAVA запустить

```
package sqltest;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class SQLtest {


    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school_db?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=GMT";
    private static final String user = "root";
    private static final String password = "123456";





    private static Connection con;
    private static Statement stmt;
    private static ResultSet rs;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String query = "select count(*) from student";

        try {

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);


            stmt = con.createStatement();


            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while (rs.next()) {
                int count = rs.getInt(1);
                System.out.println("Students : " + count);
            }

        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            sqlEx.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try { con.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { }
            try { stmt.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { }
            try { rs.close(); } catch(SQLException se) {  }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: С прошлым вопросом получилось разобраться? Не зная структуры БД, ничего кроме `select * from student` подсказать вам нельзя.

Comment: я умею работать с базой данных, могу вывести кодам MYSQl. Но как его реализовать в JAVA

Comment: Проблема с чем, с составлением запроса или с тем как его данные в Java получить?

Comment: у меня получилось вывести имена и фамилии и тд в самой базе данных. Но я хочу его через netbeans в JAVA запустить

Comment: Начните с того, что уточните это в вопросе (кнопка "править").

Comment: Правил, вы не можете подсказать как реализовать задачу

Comment: Сначала заменяете содержимое переменной `query` на запрос выбирающий имена и фамилии, а потом меняете `rs.getInt(1)` на `rs.getString(1)`.

Comment: while (rs.next()) {
                int count = rs.getString(1);
                System.out.println("Students : " + count);

Comment: Вот так? там ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вывели не количество, а их id в базе. rs.getInt(1) - означает получить значение в первой колонке у текущей записи. Другие значения получайте так же в соответствии с вашей структурой бд.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        String query = "select * from student";

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt(1);
                String firstName = rs.getString(2);
                String lastName = rs.getString(3);
                System.out.println("Students : " + id + " " + firstName + " " + lastName);
            }

        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            sqlEx.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try { con.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { }
            try { stmt.close(); } catch(SQLException se) { }
            try { rs.close(); } catch(SQLException se) {  }
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо вам) но у меня вывело null везде кроме фамилии

Comment: query поменяли?

Comment: не копипастите мой код. Я же вручную пишу, ошибки свои плохо вижу )

Comment: SELECT pupil.name ,pupil.surname,mark_value.values FROM pupil ,mark_value ,mark  WHERE pupil.id=mark.pupil_id AND mark.mark_id=mark_value.id;

Comment: Вот такой запрос, там места исправил некоторые вроде код без ошибок

Comment: Он как раз выводит количество (count(*)).

Comment: да. невнимательность